# Enviar Boleto.net por email

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação console que todos os dias durante a madrugada deverá enviar  boletos para os clientes, o acesso e retorno do BD tá ok, o sistema retorna uma lista com todos os dados do cliente/Boleto, no exemplo do código:

```
string vencimento = "2015-06-04 00:00:00.000";;
            String valorBoleto = "123.11";
            String numeroDocumento = "B20005446";

            //cedente
            String cedente_codigo = "1111111";
            String cedente_nossoNumeroBoleto = "22222222";
            String cedente_cpfCnpj = "123.456.789-01";
            String cedente_nome = "PAULO FREIRE - FOUR FREIRES INF.";
            String cedente_agencia = "1000";
            String cedente_conta = "22507";
            String cedente_digitoConta = "6";

            //sacado
            String sacado_cpfCnpj = "000.000.000-00";
            String sacado_nome = "JOÃO";
            String sacado_endereco = "RUA XV";
            String sacado_bairro = "";
            String sacado_cidade = "";
            String sacado_cep = "";
            String sacado_uf = "";

            Cedente cedente = new Cedente(cedente_cpfCnpj,
            cedente_nome,
            cedente_agencia,
            cedente_conta,
            cedente_digitoConta);

            cedente.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(cedente_codigo);

            Boleto boleto = new Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(vencimento), Convert.ToDouble(valorBoleto), "109",  cedente_nossoNumeroBoleto, cedente);
            boleto.NumeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;

            Sacado sacado = new Sacado(sacado_cpfCnpj, sacado_nome);
            boleto.Sacado = sacado;
            boleto.Sacado.Endereco.End = sacado_endereco;
            boleto.Sacado.Endereco.Bairro = sacado_bairro;
            boleto.Sacado.Endereco.Cidade = sacado_cidade;
            boleto.Sacado.Endereco.CEP = sacado_cep;
            boleto.Sacado.Endereco.UF = sacado_uf;

            Instrucao_Itau instrucao = new Instrucao_Itau();
            instrucao.Descricao = "Não Receber após o vencimento";

            boleto.Instrucoes.Add(instrucao);
            EspecieDocumento_Itau especie = new EspecieDocumento_Itau(99);
            boleto.EspecieDocumento = especie;

            BoletoBancario boleto_bancario = new BoletoBancario();
            boleto_bancario.CodigoBanco = 341;
            boleto_bancario.Boleto = boleto;
            boleto_bancario.MostrarCodigoCarteira = true;
            boleto_bancario.Boleto.Valida();

            boleto_bancario.MostrarComprovanteEntrega = true;


            pnl_dados.Visible = false;

            pnl_boleto.Controls.Add(boleto_bancario);
```

O problema é que não sei como ANEXAR o Boleto gerado por essa dll [Boleto.net](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet) ao email do cliente, porque do jeito que está o boleto é carregado na tela pra impressão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No próprio GitHub do Boleto.Net possui um exemplo de como fazer o envio para e-mail, para verificar basta acessar [src/Boleto.Net.Site](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/tree/master/src/Boleto.Net.Site).

Aqui está o exemplo postado em `.aspx`, mas você pode adaptar ao seu contexto.

```
protected MailMessage PreparaMail()
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox1.Text));
        mail.Subject = "Teste de envio de Boleto Bancário";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        return mail;
    }

    protected BoletoBancario PreparaBoleto()
    {
        DateTime vencimento = new DateTime(2007, 9, 10);

        Instrucao_Itau item1 = new Instrucao_Itau(9, 5);
        Instrucao_Itau item2 = new Instrucao_Itau(81, 10);
        Cedente c = new Cedente("00.000.000/0000-00", "Empresa de Atacado", "0542", "13000");
        //Na carteira 198 o código do Cedente é a conta bancária
        c.Codigo = "13000";

        Boleto b = new Boleto(vencimento, 1642, "198", "92082835", c);
        b.NumeroDocumento = "1008073";

        b.Sacado = new Sacado("000.000.000-00", "Fulano de Silva");
        b.Sacado.Endereco.End = "SSS 154 Bloco J Casa 23";
        b.Sacado.Endereco.Bairro = "Testando";
        b.Sacado.Endereco.Cidade = "Testelândia";
        b.Sacado.Endereco.CEP = "70000000";
        b.Sacado.Endereco.UF = "DF";

        item2.Descricao += " " + item2.QuantidadeDias.ToString() + " dias corridos do vencimento.";
        b.Instrucoes.Add(item1);
        b.Instrucoes.Add(item2);



        BoletoBancario itau = new BoletoBancario();
        itau.CodigoBanco = 341;
        itau.Boleto = b;

        return itau;
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        BoletoBancario  itau = PreparaBoleto();
        MailMessage mail = PreparaMail();

        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            mail.Subject += " - On-Line";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(itau);

            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlTW = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            Panel1.RenderControl(htmlTW);
            string html = sw.ToString();
            //
            mail.Body = html;
        }
        else
        {
            mail.Subject += " - Off-Line";
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(itau.HtmlBoletoParaEnvioEmail());
        }

        MandaEmail(mail);
        Label1.Text = "Boleto simples enviado para o email: " + TextBox1.Text;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BoletoBancario itau = PreparaBoleto();

        // embora estou mandando o mesmo boleto duas vezes, voce pode obviamente mandar boletos distintos
        BoletoBancario[] arrayDeBoletos = new BoletoBancario[] { itau, itau };
        AlternateView  av = BoletoBancario.GeraHtmlDeVariosBoletosParaEmail("Isto é um email com <b>dois</b> boletos", arrayDeBoletos);

        MailMessage  mail = PreparaMail();
        mail.Subject += " - Off-Line - Múltiplo";
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(av);

        MandaEmail(mail);
        Label1.Text = "Boleto múltimplo enviado para o email: " + TextBox1.Text;
    }


    void MandaEmail(MailMessage mail)
    {
        SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        objSmtpClient.Host = "smtp.dominio.com.br";
        objSmtpClient.Port = 25;
        objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        objSmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("stiven@callas.com.br", "123456");
        objSmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        objSmtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
        objSmtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
```

Comment: Perfeito!, porém o código de barras não é exibido completamente...outra dúvida: pelo que vejo para os demais bancos é só instanciar novamente a classe `BoletoBancario BB = new BoletoBancario()` e demais particularidades em relação as Instruções, etc;

Answer (score 1):

Estou passando por algo parecido, o que fiz foi primeiro salvar o HTML do boleto gerado em disco, pra depois utilizá-lo, no meu caso tenho que subir ele pro storage do azure. No caso do e-mail seria só alterar pra inserir o arquivo gerado no anexo.

Para salvar o arquivo em disco utilizei o pacote do nuget [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin).

Segue exemplo do código:

```
public void SalvarPdfEmDisco(string htmlBoleto, string nomeArquivo, out string caminhoBoleto)
{
    byte[] pdfBuf = new SimplePechkin(new Pechkin.GlobalConfig()).Convert(htmlBoleto);

    caminhoBoleto = "C:\\boletos\\" + nomeArquivo + ".pdf";

    File.WriteAllBytes(caminhoBoleto, pdfBuf);
}
```

Depois é só passar o caminho do arquivo retornado no método para o método responsável por enviar o e-mail.

```
protected MailMessage EnviaEmail(string caminhoArquivo)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("emailparaenviar@email.com"));
    mail.Subject = "Envio de Boleto Bancário";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(caminhoArquivo));
    return mail;
}
```